# WooCommerce does not show sub categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I installed WooCommerce. WooCommerce setup 5 pages like: Shop, Cart, Account, Privacy and Pay.

Everything works fine but WooCommerce shows only the main categories.

My settings in the WooCommerce dashboard set to show subcategories but nothing is happening.

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to a default theme like Twenty Seventeen, do the sub-categories show up?

If so, I would suggest talking to your theme author.

If not, Try re-saving your products and categories and clearing the cache.

Comment: Hi Ali, ok I select a default theme and I have subcategories but the default style from Woocommerce is not loading. I cleared the cache but the style is horrible.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I added the woocommerce support in my theme.
Then I created a new page called woocommerce.php
In this fil you run a loop with woocommerce_content();
This line is required in div tags with class woocommerce.
This is important for the default style!

The file look like this

```
<div class=“woocommerce”>
<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
</div>
```